# Adding labels to datapoints on plot in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I'm trying to put labels on the datapoints in a plot that find the top 5 countries with the smallest population.

```
Smallestpop.order = order(population$X2014)
smallref = population[Smallestpop.order,]
smallref[1:5,]
plot(smallref[1:5,3:,])
 text(smallref[1:5],labels=smallref$Country.Code[1:5],adj = NULL,
 pos = 1, offset = 0.5, vfont = NULL,
 cex = 1, col = NULL, font = NULL)
```

This is how the plot currently looks like

[image]

but I would like to have the country code on each of the datapoints.
Is this possible?

Comment: share a reproducible data for us to work on!

Answer (score 0):

`scatterplotMatrix()` in the `car` package has an arg `id.n` to control point labeling and `id.method` to provode a variety of methods.

You want to use something like

```
scatterplotMatrix(population, id.n=5, id.method="y")
```

By default, row names of the observations are used as point labels.